# How to publish a Shopify App as Beta

Tags: shopify

I have a Shopify App that I would like to test in the App marketplace as a beta.  According to this link in the [docs](http://wiki.shopify.com/Shopify_App_Development#Beta_test_with_merchants_.26_friends), it says I should be able to click 'Publish Beta App' at the top of the app listing to make it public.  I do not see that option in the submission, I only see a submit button and the categories do not show a beta option.  Can someone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, you have to just click on "App Store Publishing" and fill in the form. After that you application will become 'Beta' and you will be able to request a review from Shopify to become published.

In other words, there is no dedicated button to publish beta.

Comment: What happens when it's in beta? I literately can find no info.